# RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute() not executing Javascript function

Tags: javascript, java, jsf, primefaces, requestcontext

I've been fiddling with this for a while and have not been able to get this working. There is probably something I am not understanding correctly. I want to call into a Javascript function from my managed bean's Java code. The onSubmit method looks like this: (by setting a breakpoint, I know this code is executing)

```
RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.execute("showOrHideModal(\'show\');");
```

The showOrHideModal function is located within a .js file at the head of the xhtml. The button on the xhtml looks like this:

```
<p:commandButton
    id="submit"
    action="#{bean.onSubmit}"
    value="Submit"
    accesskey="S"
    onclick="{some javascript}"
    title="Click to Submit"
/>
```

The reason I need this code in the bean is because I will need to later run some validations and conditionally execute this Javascript to show a modal window.

When I click the button while debugging, I don't get any feedback, so it's hard to start looking for the problem. I even added console.writeLine's to the Javascript function. My IDE is IntelliJ 14.1.4 if that helps - I would love to find out a way to debug this.

Also, if there is another solution that you see for my overall problem, let me know. I may have formed tunnel vision on this issue.

Comment: I don't know why you escape the single quote, it doesn't need to be escaped. Apart of this, are you sure that: 1) there's no exception thrown while `bean#onSubmit` is executed in the server side, and 2) the javascript method receives the proper parameters and it doesn't fail?

Comment: And check the browser console to see that it ends up in the ajax response

Comment: In my case popup windows where blocked by the browser. Looks like you are also trying to open a new window.